# How to merge 2 duplicated database entry to 1 database after M&A?

Tags: java, database, jobs

After M&A (Mergers and acquisitions) 2 companies, we have 2 database systems with many duplicated data.

For example : 2 companies are Amazon and Alibaba, so I have many case like that : one customer bought the products from both of them. So I have 2 customer inside 2 database, but after M&A, I have to merge that to 1 database which store 1 customer will all productions which already bought by this customer.

P/s : 2 databases don't have the same schema.
Do you know any solution for this problem ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic procedure:

1. Make sure all your apps are writing to only one database, but reading from both as needed. If the schemas are very different you might need a wrapper app/library around the old database to wrangle things into the right shape for your apps.
2. Once nothing is writing to the old database, you can create a process to read out the old records, transform them as needed, and load them into the new database. You'll have to make some decisions (together with business people) about what data to keep from the old database and how to transform it to fit into the new one.
3. Stop your apps from reading from the old database.
4. Remove the old database.

You'll need a lot of testing, preferably automated.

An alternative is to create a new DB with a schema that covers everything from both databases, but this may not be possible or desirable.

You can also search about "data migration" for more info.

Comment: Best thank @Ryan, that's exactly what I'm looking for.